# How do I test my addon in Firefox Developer Edition?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to test my extension in Firefox 44+ as I got a compatibility warning about it using files that have been moved in newer versions. I have Firefox 43 which works, and I have Firefox Developer Edition, in which I can't seem to set it to enable.

I temporarily enable [Developer Debugging Preferences](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/extension-developer/) , so I can immediately see my changes (addon installed in regular Fx and Dev edition). I have my addon directory set in profile .dev-edition-default/extensions.ini file same in both of them, but it doesn't show up in Firefox Developer Edition. - not when I put it under `[ExtensionDirs]`, or `[MultiprocessIncompatibleExtensions]`

So how do I test my addon in Firefox Developer edition?

Comment: Not sure exactly what your setup is, but `jpm` has an argument to choose the Firefox binary to run with. On OS X: `jpm run -b /Applications/FirefoxDeveloperEdition.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox`

Comment: What is JPM, what does it do?

Comment: jpm is the new Mozilla add-on tool. If you're not using it though, I suppose it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Load it as a temporary addon - https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/12/23/loading-temporary-add-ons/

Comment: Thanks for the info! Does this mean no traditional addons, only SDK addons in the future!?

Comment: @NoBugs they will be announcing clarification on that soon, I cant be certain till then.